# WooCommerce Rest API JSON formate Complex implementation in Swift

Tags: swift5

I want to get the products for each categories.For example in Swift5, tableview have multiple cells and  cells contains, category name(FF) and collection view (all products for FF).But the JSON formate is so mix of categories in WooCommerce, how can I get the products for each categories.  I am hitting this Woocommerece API https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?consumer_key=XXX&consumer_secret=XXX

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass a parameter in the URL something like that: `filter[category]=Bedroom`

Comment: yes but it only give me 1 category's data not all data for specifics categories